# Where does Django request object originated in `class View`?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Here is the code segment I am [referring to](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7da3923ba0c569aa23d0ab0a47a124af60a18f5b/django/views/generic/base.py)

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    """
    Main entry point for a request-response process.
    """
    for key in initkwargs:
        if key in cls.http_method_names:
            raise TypeError("You tried to pass in the %s method name as a "
                            "keyword argument to %s(). Don't do that."
                            % (key, cls.__name__))
        if not hasattr(cls, key):
            raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
                            "only accepts arguments that are already "
                            "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key))

    def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self = cls(**initkwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
            self.head = self.get
        self.request = request
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    view.view_class = cls
    view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs

    # take name and docstring from class
    update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())

    # and possible attributes set by decorators
    # like csrf_exempt from dispatch
    update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
    return view
```

I am looking for the code that the request object is passed in to.

The common place where as_view is used is in [url](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)

However I couldn't reference to request object in

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix=''):
    if isinstance(view, (list, tuple)):
        # For include(...) processing.
        urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
        return RegexURLResolver(regex, urlconf_module, kwargs, app_name=app_name, namespace=namespace)
    else:
        if isinstance(view, six.string_types):
            warnings.warn(
                'Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and '
                'will be removed in Django 1.10 (got %s). Pass the callable '
               'instead.' % view,
            RemovedInDjango110Warning, stacklevel=2
            )
            if not view:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Empty URL pattern view name not permitted (for pattern %r)' % regex)
            if prefix:
                view = prefix + '.' + view
        return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
```

Can someone point me a direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the request is never passed to `as_view()`.

The `as_view()` method is called when the url config is loaded, before any requests are handled. It defines a method `view`, and returns it.

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
return view
```

This `view` method takes an argument `request`, positional and keyword arguments. The `view` method is then passed to the url instance. Note that `url` simply requires a callable that takes a `request` argument. This could be a callable returned by calling `as_view()` for a class based view, or a regular function based view, it makes no difference to how the request is passed to the view.

```
def function_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("I'm a function based view")

url(r'^cbv/$', MyView.as_view()),
url(r'^fv/$', function_view),
```

Then, when a request is handled, the url is resolved into this `view`, and `BaseHandler.get_response` calls the view with the request, and args and kwargs captured from the url.

Answer (score 1):

The request is processed by [`BaseHandler.get_response`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/336512fae77ec214ad6db24166b9a8676007cc09/django/core/handlers/base.py#L94):

```
wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
try:
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The request is created from the [WSGIHandler class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7da3923ba0c569aa23d0ab0a47a124af60a18f5b/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L146).

James Bennett talks about this in [Django In Depth at around 2 hours and 14 minutes](https://youtu.be/tkwZ1jG3XgA?t=2h14m51s). Slides can be found [here](http://media.b-list.org/s/django-in-depth-2015.pdf).